# Как использовать динамичные данные в laravel-mixe?

Tags: laravel5, blade, laravel-mix

Всем доброго времени суток! У меня есть blade файл там я использую laravel-mix, но там хочу получать название файлов динамичном виде то есть:

```
let gettingJson;
        city.change( function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            cityValue = city.val();
            $('#bookingSearchBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
        gettingJson = $.getJSON("{{ mix('json/r2-c1.json', 'build') }}");
```

верхный код работает прекрасно, но я хочу динамичные данные и для того чтобы получить выбранные значение я должен поменять этот параметр `json/r2-c1.json`, но у меня не получается сделал так `gettingJson = $.getJSON("{{ mix('json/r" + cityValue + "-c1.json', 'build') }}");` но все равно не работает, пожалуйста помогите попробовал очень много варинатов все равно не получается, с кем была проблема отпишитесь, спасибо за внимание!

Comment: А какие-то ошибки пишет, а то не совсем понятно, что не получается. В панели разработчика в браузере какие-то ошибки может?

Comment: ошибка выдает, то есть не может найти `cityValue`, думаю проблема в том что внутри javascript интерпртируется php и внутри php хочу я отправить параметр из javascript, а php не слушает это, просто на стринг конертирует все

Comment: `{{ mix('json/r2-c1.json', 'build') }}` этот код равен тому, что `<?php echo e mix('json/r2-c1.json'); ?>`, но  `{{ mix('json/r" + cityValue + "-c1.json', 'build') }}` такой код не работает, `<?php echo e mix('json/r%20%20cityValue%20%20-c1.json'); ?>` такой код выводится

Comment: Понятно, вы пытаетесь переменную из JavaScript передать в PHP функцию `mix`. Но так не получится. Вам и версионирование не нужно тогда: `$.ajax({dataType: "json", url: url, cache: false, success: success})`.

Comment: мы используем кэш поэтому ваш код у нас не актуален, мы решили подругому проверяем файл mix-manifest.json и там ищем переменных там с хешом и просто название файла, и эти файлы используем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решили вопрос таким оброзам в Жаваскрипте проверили mix-manifest.json и там уже если хеш менятеся то во фронте получаем измененый значение, спасибо всем кто участвовал!